# Где нужно указывать настройки для БД Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Читаю оф. документацию по Laravel. В ней говорится, что настройки от БД можно указать в config/database.php. Указываю их там, в итоге, при попытке запустить миграцию, в консоли появляется ошибка.

Пробую указать в env настройки для БД, заново запускаю миграцию и на этот раз все работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Текст ошибки скиньте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если вы делаете по инструкции с laravel.com, то там `config/database.php` содержит такие строки:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

На примере одной строки:

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
```

`host` равен переменной `DB_HOST` в `env`-файле (если он есть) или `localhost`, если `env`-файл не подключен.

Внимательно прочитайте [Environment configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать, так как описал Zhukov Roman.
Я предпочитаю задавать настройки в файле .env (в корне созданного приложения).
В нем можно задать любые настройки из конфигов, а так же добавить любые свои.
Все переменные, описанные в этом файле, будут автоматически доступны вашему приложения в суперглобальной переменной $_ENV и вы сможете использовать их везде в своем приложении.

Часто необходимо иметь разные значения для разных настроек в зависимости от среды, в которой выполняется приложение. Например, вы можете захотеть использовать разные драйвера (или настройки) на локальном сервере и на продакшне. 
Т.о. вы можете изменять эти переменные под свои нужны, как на локальной машине, так и в продакшне.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее указывать эти настройки в .env файле. Если файла нет - создайте его, в консоли (если находитесь в директории с проектом):

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Далее в нем указываете:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Другие настройки, такие как почта и т.п. тоже указываются в этом файле. Почему именно в этом файле? Например при совместной работе через git у других участников не будет проблем с подключением к своей локальной БД.